# How do I add text/signature or attachment to an Outlook rule forwarded message?

Tags: outlook, rule

I have created an Outlook rule that forwards an email to a group based on the the subject line.

But now I want to add text, signature or an attachment to the email I am forwarding.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign a VBA macro sub to the rule (i.e. change the rule to run a macro). The VBA macro sub should look like the following one:

```
public sub test(mail as MailItem)
  ' do whatever you need
end sub
```

Where the mail object passed as parameter represents the incoming mail item.

Note, in that case you need to do all the operations in the code. Use the [Reply](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff868875.aspx) method to create a reply, pre-addressed to the original sender, from the original message. The following properties can be used to modify the message body:

1. Body - a raw text.
2. HTMLBody - an HTML markup which represents the message body.
3. The Word editor. The WordEditor property of the Inspector class returns an instance of the Word document which represents the message body.

You can read more about all these ways in the [Chapter 17: Working with Item Bodies](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492012(v=office.12).aspx) in MSDN.

To add an attachment to the reply message, you need to use the Add method of the Attachments class (see the corresponding property of the MailItem class).